# withLatestFrom operator does not tick on null value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

In an Angular project using `@ngrx/effect` we have an observable stream using `withLatestFrom` rxjs operator.

Here is our observable effect stream:

```
@Effect()
handleUsersData$ = this.actions$
.pipe(
    ofType(HANDLE_USER_DATA),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.pipe(select(getCurrentUserId)),
      this.store.pipe(select(getUserEntities)),
    ),
    tap(([action, currentUserId, users]) => console.log(([action, currentUserId, users]))),
    switchMap(([action, currentUserId, users]) => {
      const dispatchedActions: Action[] = [];

      if (currentUserId) {
        dispatchedActions.push(new SetCurrentUser()); 
      } else {
        dispatchedActions.push(new SomeAction());
        dispatchedActions.push(new ClearUsers());
      }

      return dispatchedActions;
    })
);
```

One of the selectors we use is the following:

```
export const getCurrentUserId = createSelector(
  getUserEntities,
  getRouterStateUrl,
  (users: Dictionary<User>, router: RouterStateUrl) => {

    return router.params && users[router.params.userId] || null;
  }
);
```

When `userId` is defined, the actions are dispatched properly. The `console.log` displays user ID and user entities.

But if `userId` is not among router params, the selector returns `null` and the observable stream never ticks. `console.log` in the `tap` returns nothing`

Why does `withLatestFrom` seem to ignore `null` value and just not tick if this value is the result of the selector? It's a valid value in our context.

How to ensure that the observable stream ticks even if there is a null value in `getCurrentUserId` selector?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to use `combineLatest` instead.

`withLatestFrom` doesn't ignore `null`. It's a regular value. However, `withLatestFrom` reacts only on emissions from its direct source. That's from  `this.actions$.pipe(ofType(HANDLE_USER_DATA))`. It keeps emissions  from other sources as well but it only keeps them in its internal buffer and doesn't react to them.

On the other hand `combineLatest` will emit on every emission from every source Observable after they all emit at least one item (have a look at `startWith` if you want to be sure all sources emit at least once).

Comment: Im not involved in that thread but thank you for the explanation. Here is also a good explanation about when to use withLatestFrom: https://medium.com/@martinkonicek/rx-combinelatest-vs-withlatestfrom-ccd98cc1cd41

Comment: Where would you place startWith then to ensure my selectors produce at least a null value?

Comment: You need to use it for each source Observable `withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getCurrentUserId), startWith(42)), ...)`

Comment: I kinda feel the error is something else. Have you tried `console.log()` right before the statement of `return router.params && users[router.params.userId] || null;` ? It might not even gets executed. Not really because it's null.